# Tire and Elasticsearch SearchRequestFailed SearchPhaseExecutionException

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, elasticsearch, tire

I'm implemented Tire wih elasticsearch.
Locally my project runs fine and I have no trouble searching my index.
But when I deployed my app to my server I got this error message:

Tire::Search::SearchRequestFailed (500 : {"error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to  execute phase [query_fetch], total failure; shardFailures {[hDTlT_K_Sl6P5regwKNJyg][articles] [0]: QueryPhaseExecutionException[[articles][0]: query[ConstantScore(NotDeleted(cache(_type:article)))],from[0],size[25],sort[!]: Query     Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: IOException[Can't sort on string types with more than one value per doc, or more than one token per field]; }]","status":500}):

I believe my articles are stored in my index because I didn't receive any errors creating them. I also tried to run the same query manually with this:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/articles/article/_search' -d '{ 
    "sort": [ 
        { 
            "supplier_code": "desc" 
        } 
    ] 
}'
```

And I got practically the same response:

{"error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query_fetch], total failure; shardFailures {[hDTlT_K_Sl6P5regwKNJyg][articles][0]: QueryPhaseExecutionException[[articles][0]: query[ConstantScore(NotDeleted(cache(_type:article)))],from[0],size[10],sort[!]: Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: IOException[Can't sort on string types with more than one value per doc, or more than one token per field]; }]","status":500}

So can Anybody point me in the right direction?
I copied the exact sam config I use on my local machine.
So strange it doesn't work on the server.

What am I missing here?

Thanks a lot in advance

EDIT:

I found out that the sort I'm trying to perform is causing the issue.
Also that is has something to do with the mapping of my article object to elastic search.

Something with the field I'm trying to sort put on not_analyzed I'm I correct?
Do I need to explicitly map all my fields if I map one field only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the actual issue: **Can't sort on string types with more than one value per doc, or more than one token per field.** It means one of two things: either you have multiple `supplier_code` fields per document or the field `supplier_code` is analyzed by an analyzer the produces multiple tokens (default analyzer would do that for some strings). Elasticsearch can only sort on fields that contains no more than one value per record. So, if you have multiple fields, you need to come up with another sort key or if you have a single field, you need to make it not_analyzed, or use some other analyzer that doesn't produce multiple tokens.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, what kind of analyzer could I use so I can use the field for searching and sorting? 
Also if I add some mapping do I need to explicitly map all my fields of my model?

Comment: It depends on your search use case. Any analyzer that produces no more than one token would do. If your use case requires splitting the content of the field into multiple tokens, you can use [Multi Field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/multi-field-type.html) to index the field twice. You can map only one field, leaving all other fields dynamic. However, if field was already mapped dynamically, you need to recreate the index.